# JSON date parser, posting as day less

Tags: java, json, rest, date, jersey

I am having a problem with jersey rest services while posting java.util.Date fields.

Here is the service request in JSON format.

```
{
"fromDate":"2012-06-30",
"toDate":"2013-07-01"
}
```

when the same JSON object is mapped to java object. Dates are converted as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<search>
  <fromDate>2012-06-29T19:00:00-05:00</fromDate>
  <toDate>2013-06-30T19:00:00-05:00</toDate>
</search>
```

Any idea or any clue why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates represent the same moment. The first ones are in UTC, and the second ones are in UTC minus 5 hours.

```
2012-06-29T19:00:00-05:00
```

is the 29th of June at 19:00 in a timezone which is 5 hours after UTC.

So if you express this date in UTC time, you have to add 5 hours, which gives back the date

```
2012-06-30T00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you share what's the Best practice to work with dates?

Comment: @javabie Best practice is: **"Work/Think/Store globally, Display locally"**. Most of your business logic and storage in database should be it [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT. Generally, you only convert to a zoned date-time when displaying to the user (in interface of the app), or the user impacts the business logic. Like "Report on today's sales figures" where "today" means the user's own local time zone. And *always* think about time-zones when doing date-time work, just like you should *always* think about character encoding when working with text files.

Answer (score 1):

The times should be a hint.  They are 5 hours apart, so this is a timezone adjustment problem.  The JSON times were interpreted as UTC and then adjusted to EDT.